# Is there a way to access local filesystem on Oculus Browser?

Tags: browser, filesystems, webvr, oculus, quest

i'm currently playing some 360 video files, using WebVr (a-frame).

Sometimes i need to play them on my local folder.

I'm using a Quest with Oculus Browser (but i can easily switch to Firefox Reality)

Is there a way to access the classical "DCIM" folder on Oculus Quest (enabling the correct flag obviously ? )

I tried with src = mnt/sdcard or src = storage

etc etc. with no luck.

in firefox Reality (for example) i saw that in the browser i can easily access to 
`storage/emulated/0/DCIM`

but when i reference a simple jpg in my super simple html file, it doesn't show up

Thanks in advance.

Victor

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where is the "super simple html file" being served from?